# Integrals. Derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Can someone help me solve this ? Thanks !

We have : $F(x)  = \displaystyle\int_{3x}^{\sqrt \pi}\sin(t^2) dt$

Find : $F'(x)$ , the derivative of $F(x)$.

I tried to solve it and I found the answer : -1-sin(9x^2)

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: I tried to solve it and i found the answer -1-sin(9x^2) but I don't know if it's correct. That's why I'm searching for some help. Thanks .

Comment: @MariaBluee Had you said this earlier you would not have received so many downvotes. Now you should tell us how you got it. What substitution you applied, what formula/theorem you used etc. Once you  do all this, I will up vote this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your integral to $-\int_{\sqrt{\pi}}^{3x}\sin t^2dt $. Then using transformation of variable you obtain that $-\int_{\sqrt{\pi}}^{3x}\sin t^2dt=-3\int_{\sqrt{\pi}/3}^{x}\sin 9t^2dt $. Therefor the derivative is $-3\sin 9x^2$.